# Vim replace with unicode character

Tags: regex, unicode, vim

I've seen hints on how to search for unicode characters in vim using :help regexp and \%u , but I have not been able to figure out how to replace text with a hex-defined unicode character.

The particular situation is that a DefaultKeyBindings.dict needs comments that will print the character mapped in that line in a comment.

Begin:

```
blah blah...\U2234
```

Command:

```
:s/\v.*\\U(\d{4})/& \/\*\\\\%u\1 \*\/
```

Result:

```
blah blah...\U2234 /*\%u2234 */
```

Goal:

```
blah blah...\U2234 /* ∴ */
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to convert the string representation of the hexadecimal Unicode value into the actual character represented by it. This is a task for `nr2char()`, which can be embedded into the substitution via `:help sub-replace-expression`:

```
:substitute+\v.*\\U(\d{4})\zs+\='/* '.nr2char(str2nr(submatch(1),16)).' */'+
```

Protip: Use a different separator (I chose `+` over `/`), then you don't need to escape.

Comment: Ha, beat me to it, and a better answer, too, with nice use of `\zs` and `str2nr()`. Note that `'encoding'` must be set to UTF-8 to make `nr2char()` work, see [`:h nr2char()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#nr2char%28%29).

Answer (score 4):

You can use an expression in the substitution text with `\=`. Combine this with the `nr2char()` function for a workable solution. Here's a start:

```
s^.*\\U\(\d\{4}\)^\=submatch(0).' // '.nr2char(printf('%d','0x'.submatch(1)))
```

This will convert the line

```
Bla bla ... \U2234
```

to

```
Bla bla ... \U2234 // ∴
```

I use `printf()` for the conversion from hex to decimal number as required by the `nr2char()` function. I'm sure this can be improved.

Note that you must set `'encoding'` to UTF-8 for this to work, see [`:h nr2char()`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/eval.html#nr2char%28%29).

Answer (score 1):

Not nearly as elegant, but included here for future readers.

```
:%s#\U2234#/* ∴ */#
```

and type Control-V u 2 2 3 4 to create the character right there in the expression.

Related note 'ga' on a character will tell you the Unicode value as well as the digraph method of typing it if available.